# DecimalFormat for price formatting in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

Is it possible to format price according to rules like this using DecimalFormat in Java:
**50000 => 50 000 rub 00 kop**

Comment: Not sure why this got downvotes. I think it is a fair question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
```

probably does what you want.

It might use symbols instead of words for roubles and kopeks.

Here's a working example:

```
    final NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    currencyInstance.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("RUB"));
    System.out.println(currencyInstance.format(50000));
```

This output for me:

> RUB50,000.00

which is not exactly what you asked for. But it is a start.

This alternative

```
final NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
System.out.println(currencyInstance.format(50000.01));
```

gave me

> 50 000,01 руб

Comment: Thanks for answer! But if I want to Use DecimalFormat & program this myself (for example, I not sure that this will works in GWT), is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using .Net you can format the output using;

```
<%
  String format = "<p>{0:#,0 rub .00 kop}</p>";
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 98765.4321));
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 98765.4));
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 987654321));
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 0.12345));
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 0.1));
  Response.Write(String.Format(format, 0));
%>
```

Which outputs;

```
 98,765 rub .43 kop
 98,765 rub .40 kop
 987,654,321 rub .00 kop
 0 rub .12 kop
 0 rub .10 kop
 0 rub .00 kop
```

Not sure how to get rid of the decimal place though and omit if kop == zero.

You can also format +/ve -/ve strings differently see; http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/